# Confusion about the derivative of log(x)

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, logarithms

so $log(x)$ has this graph:
[$log(x)$ Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRA7S.png)

and $\frac{1}{ln(x)}$has this graph: [$\frac{1}{ln(x)}$ Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8vIZ.png)

$\frac{1}{ln(x)}$ is the derivative of $log(x)$

My question is why does the graph of $\frac{1}{ln(x)}$ have a negative values, when all the $log(x)$ graph does is increase?

Comment: Hi, the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $1/x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial claim that $\frac1{\ln x}$ is the derivative of $\log(x)$ is not correct. The derivative of $\log_a(x)$ is $\frac1{x\ln a}$. [image]

Comment: Just realized, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to derive the derivative.
(Nothing original here.)

Since
$\log(xy)
=\log(x)+\log(y)
$,
$\log(1)=0$
and

$\begin{array}\\
\log'(x)
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\log(x+h)-\log(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\log(x)+\log(1+h/x)-\log(x))}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\log(1+h/x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\log(1+h/x)-\log(1))}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac1{x}\dfrac{\log(1+h/x)-\log(1))}{h/x}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\log(1+h)-\log(1))}{h}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\log'(1)\\
\end{array}
$

The natural log,
$\ln$.
is the one for which
$\log'(1)=1
$.